# bringing Google into IFRAMES

Tags: iframe, x-frame-options

This will not work, because Google sends `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/"></iframe>
```

Here is a way around that:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1"></iframe>
```

This, however, does not work:

```
<iframe src="https://fonts.google.com/webhp?igu=1" ></iframe>
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The page at https://fonts.google.com/webhp?igu=1 sends both X-Frame-Options and CSP:frame-ancestors which both prohibit displaying it in an iframe. The path or parameter of /webhp?igu=1 likely disbles the framing prevention.